# ¿Cómo puedo resolver este error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic, push

Estoy tratando de crear un 'CRUD' con 'firebase realtime' utilizando 'angularJs' y me sale el error del 'push'. Aquí abajo dejo un ejemplo del código. Quiero introducir tres datos de un vehículo {Matricula, Modelo y Marca} y al momento de enviar los datos sale el error del 'push'.

```
//Create 
  createBooking(cln: Cliente){
    return this.bookingListRef.push({
      Matricula: cln.matricula,
      Marca: cln.marca,
      Modelo: cln.modelo
    })
  }
  //Get Single

  getbooklist(id: string){
    this.bookingRef =this.DbFire.object('/Cliente' + id);
    return this.bookingRef;
  }
  //Get List

  getBookList(){
    this.bookingListRef = this.DbFire.list ('/Cliente');
    return this.bookingListRef;
  }
  //Update
  updateBooking(id, cln: Cliente){
    return this.bookingRef.update({
      Matricula: cln.matricula,
      Marca: cln.marca,
      Modelo: cln.modelo
    });
  }
  //Delete
  deletebooking(id: string){
    this.bookingRef = this.DbFire.object('/Cliente'+id);
    this.bookingRef.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Agrega un [mcve]

Comment: debes declarar `this.bookingListRef = [];` antes de asignarle un dicccionario ya que el metodo push solo es para arreglos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso no reconoce la variable bookingListRef como un arreglo. Primero debes declarar la variable:

bookingListRef = [];

Para que te permita utilizar el método push.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].